# How to render one object in an array at a time in?

Tags: reactjs, arrays, if-statement, state

This is my first time asking a question here, I'm a novice developer, and truly appreciate any support you can provide.

I'm currently working on a Flashcard app with an Editor page and Viewer page. My editor page/component stores the Flashcards that users create by inputting what should be on the front of the card and back of the card.

The problem I'm facing now is trying to get one flashcard at a time to show up on screen. I was able to get just the front of the cards to render but, all of the cards were rendered on screen. I'm unsure how to specify in React for only one card to display at a time.

My current code looks like this:

```
render() {
    const card = this.props.cards.map((card, i) => {
      return (
        <ul>
          <li key={i}>{card.front}</li>
        </ul>
      );
    })
```

How do I make it so only 1 index at a time shows on screen? Any insight you could provide would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: If you had another bit of state that was a way to store an index, you could just render that index.  Then you could have buttons that incremented or decremented the index which would automatically cause a render that updated your page.

Comment: As jme11 mentioned, 1. Decide which index to render. 2. Store that index in state if that needs to be changed later. 3. pass that down to child component. 4. Render card for that index only: `const card = this.props.card[index]; return <whatever>`